# How to handle zeros in target variable

Tags: self-study, predictive-models, zero-inflation

I'm working on a college assignment in introductory statistics to try to predict a certain target variable. The variable is continuous but has a high percentage (60%) with zero values. This is not bad data but the actual output.

What simple approach can I take here to model as linear regression does not seem appropriate.

All the values are positive.

We have been through the main models in class, ANOVA, Linear and Logistic, Poisson etc.

The task states a model of your choice and what factors affect the tax amount captured.

I ran a logistic regression on new variable created YIELDYN and then ran a linear regression on the non-zero values.

I'm hoping this is sufficient given there is nothing else we have done to date that I could see as been applicable.

Below is the raw scatter plot matrix

[image]

Comment: Are all the the values non-negative (or non-positive)?

Comment: Pedantic detail: the word "significant" meaning merely large, major or substantial is better replaced by some such word in any statistical context.

Comment: @NickCox, understood. Any idea how you might be able to help with this question?

Comment: I'm confused. If this is a college assignment, then there should be methods you're expected to use. If it's an open research problem, then this is an enormous topic for which there are competing models and methods. I can't see this as "introductory statistics". It's not in my view an introductory problem at all.

Comment: @lanenok feel free to ask more questions and i'll do my best to answer them

Comment: I mean, logistic regression is intended for _binary_ output (true/false, fraud/non-fraud, yes/no). How did you run it for your continuous output?

Comment: @lanenok. I added in an additional target variable YIELDYN and ran the logistic regression on that variable.

Comment: Logistic regression is *not* a classification algorithm.  It is a *probability model*.

Comment: It was indeed bad wording. Comment deleted. I meant binary target variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one has many zeros, a typical approach would be first to perform a binary classification zero/non-zero and then choose a model for non-zero values (which *really* depends on your non-zero data).
But this two-step approach is, in my opinion, beyond the "introductory statistics". Maybe you would like to clarify your question then.

Comment: Ordinal regression has a few advantages over that but does assume that the process generating the zeros has similarities to the process generating high vs. middle values.

Comment: The example is around tax fraud. Where the investigation was successful then we have the amount got from the investigation and when it is not successful there is a zero.

Comment: @Frank Harrell  Thank you for your comment. I never faced ordinal regression before, so I will read up. Now, that the actual problem ("fraud detection") is named, I would very much appreciate your opinion on the method for this case.

Comment: @colin.kane I think, for the problem itself binary classification as the first step is appropriate, since it separates fraud/non-fraud. A choice of model for non-zero values ("fraud amount") then depends very much on your independent variables (how many of them, numerical/categorical, ...). This is the area of machine learning. I am mainly confused by your words "introductory statistics". Probably in your college assignment you are supposed to do just something "quick and simple" that you have just learned in the college. ???

Comment: Ordinal regression (e.g. proportional odds model), if its assumptions are roughly satisfied, will be more efficient than running 2 models (one for the zeros).  You can get a good start on checking the assumptions using the R `rms` package `plot.xmean.ordinaly` function.

Comment: @ Frank Harrel  I appreciate your advice very much and learn from it myself. Why don't you put it as answer? Because people are more likely to read answers than all comments

Comment: @FrankHarrell I've added more detail to the question if this helps